# Unable to pull private image tag with docker and ansible

Tags: docker, ansible

I'm using ansible 2.0 to manage docker images from hub.docker.com on remote machines.

I have a private image with different tags on the hub, that I want to deploy on my machines, but only 1 tag out of 3 is working.

Here are the relevant info of my ansible conf:

tasks.yml:

```
- name: pull local images
  docker:
    image: "{{ item.image }}:{{ item.tag }}"
    pull: always
  with_items: "{{ docker_image_list }}"
  register: docker_pull_result
```

item example:

```
docker_image1:
  image: 'mynamespace/myimage'
  tag: mytag
```

result:

```
failed: [myhost] (item={u'image': u'mynamespace/myimage', u'tag': u'mytag'}) => {"failed": true, "item": {"image": "mynamespace/myimage", "local": "localhost:5000/mytag", "tag": "mytag"}, "module_stderr": "", "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/home/myuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1471514200.43-222544910756770/docker\", line 3752, in <module>\r\n    main()\r\n  File \"/home/myuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1471514200.43-222544910756770/docker\", line 1744, in main\r\n    stopped(manager, containers, count, name)\r\n  File \"/home/myuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1471514200.43-222544910756770/docker\", line 1623, in stopped\r\n    containers.refresh()\r\n  File \"/home/myuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1471514200.43-222544910756770/docker\", line 1531, in refresh\r\n    self.deployed = self.manager.get_deployed_containers()\r\n  File \"/home/myuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1471514200.43-222544910756770/docker\", line 1347, in get_deployed_containers\r\n    repo_tags = self.get_image_repo_tags()\r\n  File \"/home/myuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1471514200.43-222544910756770/docker\", line 1010, in get_image_repo_tags\r\n    if resource in image.get('RepoTags', []):\r\nTypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "parsed": false}
```

I don't understand why it fails and how I can fix this issue, can anyone help ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

The task fails because the `docker` module does not support referencing `tags` in the image parameter.

The [docker module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/docker_module.html#deprecated) is deprecated as of `Ansible 2.2`.

I suggest you update your Ansible version and use the recommended [docker_image](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/docker_image_module.html) and [docker_container](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/docker_container_module.html) which both support referencing `tags` by using `name:tag`.

Comment: Yeah I saw the new modules but I'm not yet able to update to superior versions of ansible because of others deprecations, maybe I'll have to deal with this sooner than I expected. If the standard docker module does not support, why does this work with one of the tag ?

Comment: So I used it again today and it started to work again, not really sure why.